# Time Format Problem integer value to time

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime, time

i don't understand convert time problem like this.

287779394  =  17:39:42 238172446 = 14:50:57  152830465 = 09:28:02

What is this format? And how can i convert time to integer value?
i'm using C# visual studio Asp MVC Project?

Comment: You are going to need to give us more hints.  It's not a "Unix time stamp".  For example, a Unix time stamp of `287779394` resolves to `Tue Feb 13 1979 18:43:14 UTC`,  There are many ways encode time.  Try doing some integer division (and modulus operations) (by 24, by 60, by 60) to see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's one byte for each of hours, minutes and seconds, with another byte value of unknown meaning (could be 1/100th seconds?):

```
var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(287779394);

Console.WriteLine($"Unknown: {bytes[0]}"); // 66
Console.WriteLine($"Seconds: {bytes[1]}"); // 42
Console.WriteLine($"Minutes: {bytes[2]}"); // 39
Console.WriteLine($"Hours:   {bytes[3]}"); // 17
```

If this is correct then an efficient way to convert the `int` to a time is:

```
int value = 287779394;

int unknown = (value >>  0) & 0xff;
int seconds = (value >>  8) & 0xff;
int minutes = (value >> 16) & 0xff;
int hours   = (value >> 24) & 0xff;

Console.WriteLine($"Time = {hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}, extra = {unknown}");
```